# Use the "logcat -b radio" in unroot phone

Tags: android, adb, logcat

I have tried to execute `logcat -b radio` programmatically, but failed. The command can be executed successfully  from a PC terminal while the device is connected.

So I want to connect adbd service directly on the phone. Is there any method to connect adbd? Perhaps with a socket or usb driver? Who can give some advice on this?

Comment: If you get adbd into tcp mode it's worth seeing if you can connect locally.  However tcp mode seems unreliable and may frequently need to be re-enabled with a cable.  Did you know it's possible to use a host-capable device and an otg cable to access adb on another?

Comment: @njzk2 obviously a permission issue.  adbd runs as the "shell" user with privileges that application code running under app userid's cannot get.

Answer (score 0):

The READ_LOGS permission control is changed since Android 4.1. Normal application cannot read the logs generated by other process (**with different UID**).

However, you can still get this permission manually by execute

`"pm grant com.yourpackage.name android.permission.READ_LOGS"`

on Adb shell. You might need to reboot your device after this.

Back to you question, you cannot connect to ADB daemon on your device with your application running on the same one. Another workaround for your application to read the logs is to write a daemon application to start and be daemonized on ADB shell, which will communicate with your application via IPC to get the log for you.

Comment: Thanks , I would like to try it.

Comment: I have defined "android,permission.READ_LOGS" in Mainifest file. and the worst issue with runtime.exec() function will wait always after readline function. What will Google do? oh my god.